# Advanced search with gem Tire and elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, elasticsearch, tire

I am trying use gem tire to search in my application. I have tables Areas, Cities, Hotels, Rooms and RoomInformations.

What I need is find hotel by query and other text fields as date_from, date_to and number of rooms. 
In model I have method which calculate if hotel has free rooms or not and send boolean.
How can I use this boolean method to filter the query?

Thank you

in hotel.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag search_hotels_path, :method => 'post' do %>
  <%= label_tag :query %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
  <%= label_tag 'From' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :date_f, params[:date_from] %>
  <%= label_tag 'To' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :date_to, params[:date_to] %>
  <%= label_tag 'Rooms' %>
  <%= text_field_tag :rooms, params[:rooms] %>
  <%= submit_tag :search %>
<% end %>
```

in hotel.rb

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
include Tire::Model::Search
include Tire::Model::Callbacks

belongs_to :city
belongs_to :area
has_one :area, :through => :city
has_many :rooms, :dependent => :delete_all


def search(params)

        tire.search do
            query do
                boolean do  
                    must { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
                    must { term rooms_available params, true}
                end
            end 
        end

end

self.include_root_in_json = false
def to_indexed_json
    to_json(methods: [:area_name,:city_name])
end

def area_name
    city.area.name
end
def city_name
    city.name
end


def rooms_available params
    exit
    begin_date = params[:date_from].to_date
    end_date = params[:date_to].to_date
    number_of_rooms = params[:rooms]

    rooms.each do |room|
        if room.available(begin_date, end_date, number_of_rooms)
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

end
```

Comment: Elasticsearch is first and foremost a search engine. It has extremely poor mechanism for table joins. To achieve what you want you would have to de-normalize your database into at most two tables: (Areas, Cities, Hotels) -> Hotels and (Rooms and RoomInformations) -> Rooms, and then use a Has Child query (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/has-child-query.html). However, I think you might be better off by switching to a relational database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in to_json method:

```
def to_json
  {
    :area_name => self.area_name, 
    :city_name => self.city_name,
    :rooms_available => self.rooms_available
   }.to_json
end
```

Then:

```
def search(params)

    tire.search do
        query do
            boolean do  
                must { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
                must { term rooms_available, true}
            end
        end 
    end

end
```

In this case though, it is better to put rooms_available in filter, since it's a must and you don't care about scoring on that clause.

```
def search(params)

    tire.search do
        query do
            boolean do  
                must { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
            end
        end 
        filter do
            boolean do  
               must { term rooms_available, true}
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Hope this helps :)